# Broadcast receiver run on main thread?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am using MQTT server in my app. So i am getting data as single strings instead of bulk json data. So if there is 100 records my broadcast receiver's onReceive will be called 100 times. I am extracting the data from received string and saving it to DB in this receiver class only. I know that normally broadcast receiver suns in main thread.So my app will be hanging if i follow this approach. So what is the suitable approach for this?if i want to run my receiver in separate thread what should i do?

This is how i register my receiver:

```
mMessageReceiver = new MQTTMessageReceiver();
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MQTTService.MQTT_MSG_RECEIVED_INTENT);
registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: I faced a similar problem, what I did is registering the receiver when needing to receive the data and unregistering it at the times I'm not in bad need to get the data, then repeating that along with the run-time, I donno if that can work with you.

Comment: One approach could be starting a service. On this service you could store the string until the number you want and then using an event bus library notify your UI that there´s a bulk of data you want to show.

Comment: You can run broadcast receiver in different thread .

Answer (score 1):

So I can suggest following solutions here:

1. Do not do heavy processing in BoradcastReceiver (but it seems
   that it's not an option)
2. Start a new [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or
   [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or Loader, or whatever threading mechanism you would
   like to use. So this will move computationally intensive part to
   separate thread, without blocking UI.
3. As axierjhtjz suggested you
   can run an IntentService (because it creates a separate working
   thread) with a MQTTMessageReceiver (I assume that this is your
   subclass of BroadcastReceiver) that will process data and notify UI
   thread through an additional BroadcastReceiver.

Personally I would suggest using the third way since it makes your app a bit more modular, meaning easier support and extension procedures

EDIT: I have also thought about the forth way:

4. You can register a Receiver using [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Handler)) providing a Handler object identifying the Thread that will do data processing.